# Elasticsearch start error: main ERROR Unable to locate appender

Tags: elasticsearch

My system is ubuntu 16.04, when I enable and start Elasticsearch

**Enable:**

```
systemctl enable elasticsearch.service

Synchronizing state of elasticsearch.service with SysV init with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install...
Executing /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable elasticsearch
```

**Start:**

```
systemctl enable elasticsearch.service

Job for elasticsearch.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status elasticsearch.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

show the log:

```
systemctl status elasticsearch.service

.
.
.
    elasticsearch[15708]: 2019-10-18 14:20:57,120 main ERROR Unable to locate appender "index_indexing_slowlog_rolling" for logger config "in

    elasticsearch[15708]: 2019-10-18 14:20:57,120 main ERROR Unable to locate appender "audit_rolling" for logger config "org.elasticsearch.x

    elasticsearch[15708]: 2019-10-18 14:20:57,120 main ERROR Unable to locate appender "index_search_slowlog_rolling_old" for logger config "


    elasticsearch[15708]: 2019-10-18 14:20:57,120 main ERROR Unable to locate appender "index_search_slowlog_rolling" for logger config "inde

    elasticsearch[15708]: 2019-10-18 14:20:57,121 main ERROR Unable to locate appender "deprecation_rolling_old" for logger config "org.elast

     elasticsearch[15708]: 2019-10-18 14:20:57,121 main ERROR Unable to locate appender "deprecation_rolling" for logger config "org.elasticse
.
.
.
```

It seems that some path settings are wrong?

The following is my configuration file /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml :

```
# Change Network
network.host: 0.0.0.0
# Change data path
path.data: /mnt/disks/elk/elasticsearch

 vim /etc/elasticsearch/jvm-options
 -Xms4g
 -Xmx4g

# Enable xpack.security
#discovery.seed_hosts: ["127.0.0.1"]
#discovery.type: "single-node"
#xpack.security.enabled: true
#xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: true
#xpack.license.self_generated.type: basic
~
```

I tried removing elasticsearch and reinstalling it, still can't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

What is the value of `path.logs`? If you have not configured it, it would log to default logs folder.

Ensure that the Log directory has permissions for `elasticsearch` user to read and write to it.

Alternatively, Check `/etc/sysconfig/elasticsearch` and see what's the value of variable `LOG_DIR` if you have configured it there instead of in `elasticsearch.yml`.